# Android Studio CMake build once for all build variants

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, build-variant

I have a project with C++ code (JNI) and lots of build variants and combinations. These are used to implement different brandings / flavors of the app (i.e. colors, styles, icons, ...).

For example there could be build variants for n customers :

- `customerNDebug`
- `customerNDebugproguard`
- `customerNRelease`.

Anyway, the C/C++ layer is **the same for each product flavor**.

Normally **CMake** in Android Studio compiles C code for every build variant. This makes sense if you have build variants like "`debug`" and "`release`" where the resulting code actually differs. However, for the build variants I have, the compiled output is always the same.

At the moment the compilation of C/C++ code is done using an external tool in our project and I want to compile using **CMake** in Android Studio only for proper IDE support of C/C++ code. So for me a single build would suffice.

Is it possible to tell Android Studio to build C/C++ code only once, no matter the build variants and flavors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Android Studio IDE together with CMake and Gradle will generate a series of native build tasks named with `externalNative<BuildVariant>Build` according to your build types and flavours. If you want to twist this behaviour, some workaround is as below:

1. Create an Android Studio module project which only builds your native code, e.g. `shared-native`.
2. Let the rest of your modules dependent on this project.

For this solution, you need to consider below points:

1. Put your `.so` files into a proper location that other projects can see and link with.
2. You can only include `debug` and `release` build types for this `shared-native` module project to avoid too many times of re-build. Or you can simply to let your other projects depends on the release type so that it will be built only **ONCE**.

Comment: How do I include only the `release` version? So far I use `android.variantFilter` to tell Android Studio not to build everything. This works for me and it looks super promising! Thx