# Same native code rebuilt for every build variant

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

My `build.gradle` file builds some native code:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/cpp/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have tens of build variants, and every time I switch to a different variant the same native code is built again (into a different folder), and this slows down a lot my build time.

What's the best way to build the native code only once and share it between different build flavours?

Comment: Check the answer from [Android Studio CMake build once for all build variants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53861448/8034839)